# Stack : not able to push a couple of characters into array

Tags: c, arrays, stack

I have a code to implement a stack using array, here the complete code : [here](http://ideone.com/9yBIkI)

The case is why I cannot to push more than one character, but
only one character?
but I've been clicking some variables are initialized using a `struct` for her push
some characters in the form of an array:

```
struct stackMhs {
char nama[10];
char npm[10];
char telp[10];
int size;
};

struct stackMhs stackMhsbaru;
```

This is the `push()` function with a parameter which will be the contents of data in the function `main()`:

```
void push(char nm, char np, char tel) {
if(stackMhsbaru.size != 10) {
stackMhsbaru.nama[stackMhsbaru.size + 1] = nm;
stackMhsbaru.npm[stackMhsbaru.size + 1] = np;
stackMhsbaru.telp[stackMhsbaru.size + 1] = tel;
stackMhsbaru.size++;
}
else {
printf("stack is full!");
}
}
```

The problem is when I use `'` to fill data is only one character at the `push()` function like `push('a','b','c');` when at compile no errors, but when I use `"` such as `push("aa","bb","cc");` when at compile error occurs:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:60:6: warning: passing argument 1 of 'push' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] 
 push("aa", "bb", "cc"); 
      ^ 
main.c:23:6: note: expected 'char' but argument is of type 'char *'
void push(char nm, char np, char tel) {
     ^
main.c:60:12: warning: passing argument 2 of 'push' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
push("aa", "bb", "cc");
           ^
main.c:23:6: note: expected 'char' but argument is of type 'char *'
void push(char nm, char np, char tel) {
     ^
main.c:60:18: warning: passing argument 3 of 'push' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
push("aa", "bb", "cc");
                 ^
main.c:23:6: note: expected 'char' but argument is of type 'char *'
void push(char nm, char np, char tel) {
     ^
```

My question is : any solution ?

Comment: your push function takes "char" parameters, you must replace it by char* or a string data type

Comment: Where is `size` initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, anything inside a `''` is a character (declared using `char`) and anything inside `""` represents a string which is a null terminated array of `char`s.

You cannot assign an array of `char`s to a single `char` variable, hence you see the warnings.

**Explanation of the warning:**

`warning: passing argument 1 of 'push' makes integer from pointer without a cast`

For explanation sake, assume that the compiler means `char` when it says `int`, then basically it is complaining that you are trying to assign a `char` array type to a `char` without explicitly telling compiler that you want to do so.

**Correct way of doing what you are trying:**

Pass the string character by character to the `push` function called inside a loop.

Comment: `assume that the compiler means char when it says int`. No need to assume, compiler do mean `char` which is an `integer` type.

Answer (score 1):

First you should try to care more about your code indentation, it would be easier for us to read it.

Now, for your problem : there is a huge difference in C between `'c'` and `"c"`. The first is just a character and the second is a **null terminated array of characters**, which is totally different.

When you call `push("aa", "bb", "cc");`, you are giving 3 arrays of characters to a function needing 3 characters, this is why your code does not works.

To bypass this, you can call your function multiple time with all the different characters of your array of characters :

```
char *str = "foo";
while (*str)
    push(*(str++));
```

This way, the `while` will loop in your string and call the `push()` function will all the characters available in `str`.