# Why I get null ouput and is not null when using strcpy() function?

Tags: c, function, stack

I asked this earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38653932/stack-not-able-to-push-a-couple-of-characters-into-array)

Before this problem is already finished, but it I was still confused with null output when using `strcpy()` function.

This code snippet :

```
void push(char* nm, char* np, char* tel) {
if(stackMhsbaru.size != 10) {
stackMhsbaru.nama[stackMhsbaru.size + 1] = nm;
stackMhsbaru.npm[stackMhsbaru.size + 1] = np;
stackMhsbaru.telp[stackMhsbaru.size + 1] = tel;
stackMhsbaru.size++;
}
}
```

The above code when compiled normal, no error, the output is :

```
---------------------------
nama = Febri
npm  = 067015021
telp = 08877
---------------------------
```

I change with :

```
void push(char* nm, char* np, char* tel) {
if(stackMhsbaru.size != 10) {
if(!nm)strcpy(stackMhsbaru.nama[stackMhsbaru.size + 1],nm);
if(!np)strcpy(stackMhsbaru.npm[stackMhsbaru.size + 1],np);
if(!tel)strcpy(stackMhsbaru.telp[stackMhsbaru.size + 1],tel);
stackMhsbaru.size++;
}
}
```

The above code when compiled normal, no error but the output is :

```
--------------------------- 
nama =
npm  =
telp =
---------------------------
```

Why ? No one can explain ?

Comment: remove the `!`s in those if blocks

Comment: Remember, the C language allows for the usage of whitespace in order to make your program readable. `if(!nm)strcpy(stackMhsbaru.nama[stackMhsbaru.size + 1],nm);` is rather hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
if(!nm)
```

can be read "if not `nm` is non-zero", i.e. it's only true if `nm` is false, which it only is if it's `NULL`.

You don't show how you call the function, but having a `NULL` pointer as the second argument to `strcpy()` gives undefined behavior.

You meant

```
if(nm != NULL)
```

Note that this is also more explicit, and (in my opinion although here's a sea of subjectivity) more clear. If you're not an experienced C programmer, I'd say it's a good idea to use the explicit comparison.

Comment: Thank you for answering sir :)) , I understand now.